# How to configure JBOSS 5 to include an X-Frame-options header?

Tags: jboss, clickjacking

I have been using jBoss 5.1 for deploying my applications. While testing clickjacking issue is raised. After searching many sites and blogs, I am not able to find the answer. In one of the sites I found that clickjacking is disabled if the site doesn't appear within the iframe :
    <iframe src="http://localhost:port"/>
Jboss home page is now being displayed in the iframe. Please let me know how to disable this using X-frame-options to avoid click-jacking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the steps below :
1 : Download the clickjackfilter file from the below link.
2 : Add the class folder present in clickjackfilter -> web-inf folder into your jboss -> deploy/root.war/web-inf folder.
3 : Add the filter code from the below link into the web.xml file of the root.war file 
4 : restart the server.

Now you can overcome the clickjacking issue for your server.
Please find the link below : 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Protection_for_Java_EE

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this link is not working, do you have any alternate link

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to modify the /deploy/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml file, and overwrite the org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter init-param X-Powered-By with the X-Frame-Options header, and the appropriate value that you want to set. Or you can create another entry of the filter (I haven't tested this)

Comment: I added context root as '/' & I set up when load http://localhost:8080 url to load the login page. this solution isn't work for root url. its working for root url + some other part. ex:http://localhost:8080/login.do. i tried to solve that by changing url pattern to ,/, /*, * likewise. but no luck. do you have any idea ?